# Skip the first occurence of a vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to do conditional formatting with a vlookup. The problem is that I don't know how to skip the first occurrence of the vlookup if the value that the vlookup is not the one that I want.

For example :

```
a      5
b      2
c      9
a      3    
d      4
```

Here is a table I'm looking in column A the value 'a' but if the value in column B is not '3' then I want to check the second occurrence of the value 'a' then it rechecks if the value in column B is equal to '3'.

I don't know if I'm clear but any help is welcome. Thank you!

I also tried the combo index and match.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

like this? you just combine filter and Column, and do VLookUp.

Comment: Yes it's something like this but I don't want to create a new column to compare it, I want the VlookUp to go through the lines if the condition is not complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use index and match.
This assumes the first row is the header row.
It first finds the first match and returns the row number, then it concatenate the rownumber returned +1 and does the next search from there.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("a",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",MATCH("a",A:A,0)+1,":A500")),0)+2)
```

with description

```
=INDEX(B:B, // find value in column B
MATCH("a",  // find the second "a"
INDIRECT(   // Makes the concatenated range a real range
CONCATENATE("A", // concatenate A with the rownumber it finds the first "a" on
MATCH("a",A:A,0)+1, // +1 because start next search on the next row
":A500")),0 // ":A500" change this to suit your needs. What is the range you need to find the second item within
 )+2) // +2 because header row and because +1 in the previous search
```

[image]

edit:
If it's only the row number you want then remove the INDEX from the formula.

```
=MATCH("a",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",MATCH("a",A:A,0)+1,":A500")),0)+2
```

Comment: does your solution always skip the first occurence or can I do it with an if condition ?

Comment: You could add a IF, but that is a seriously messy formula then. Do you mean if the first or second value is something then get first or second?

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm trying to do conditional formatting with a vlookup...."*

If you want to do conditional formatting you can try the following:

---

- Select column A
- New conditional formatting rule through formula:

  ```
  =AND($A1="a",$B1=3)
  ```
- Apply a format and apply

[image]

This would higlight all rows where column A = "a" and column B = 3

---

If there are several rows that would meet the criteria and you only want to highlight the very first one you could try the following formula:

```
=ROW()=MATCH(1,($A$1:$A1="a")*($B$1:$B1=3),0)
```

[image]

---

And offcourse, instead of these variables you can assign a cell reference to lookup values, e.g.:

```
=ROW()=MATCH(1,($A$1:$A1=$C$1)*($B$1:$B1=$D$1),0)
```

[image]

---

In the case the first value from column B, where column A is "a", is unknown; you can try the following formula:

```
=ROW()=MATCH(1,($A$1:$A1="a")*($B$1:$B1<>INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("a",$A$1:$A1,0))),0)
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that the value is unknown.

Comment: @Andreas That's also a possibility, true. It does matter how you read the question. I think OP knows how to conditionally format column A but don't know how to approach this with criteria in another column. However, I'll add another rule if what you suggest is true :)